# Spring @Transactional and @Service

Tags: spring, jpa, service, transactions, components

I'm working in a company where JPA @transactional are used within @Component beans. I've always been told that @Transactional should be used inside @Service beans. Does someone could explain spring mechanisms differences between those and what are the best pratctices .. and why

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.

Also, `@Service` and `@Component` are the same. `@Service` is just a stereotype that developers often use to indicate that the Spring Bean is kind of a Service (maybe in a DDD meaning or not)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no difference.
From the spring javadoc

@Component

> Indicates that an annotated class is a "component". Such classes are considered candidates for auto-detection when using annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning.
> ...

@Transactional

> Indicates that an annotated class is a "Service", originally defined by Domain-Driven Design (Evans, 2003) as "an operation offered as an interface that stands alone in the model, with no encapsulated state."
> May also indicate that a class is a "Business Service Facade" (in the Core J2EE patterns sense), or something similar. This annotation is a general-purpose stereotype and individual teams may narrow their semantics and use it as appropriate.
> This annotation serves as a specialization of @Component, allowing for implementation classes to be autodetected through classpath scanning.

Frankly speaking, they behave in the same way.

By using @Transactional annotation on a public method or class it simply creates a proxy with transaction code for you.

[IMO great explanation of @Transactional](https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-transaction-management-transactional-in-depth)

[Spring Stereotype Annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-stereotype-annotations)